# Can not load css

Tags: php, css, smarty

I am developing a site using PHP,Smarty,MySQL combination. In my web site css file is not loading. Please check the url

```
http://jobsgang.com/a9bb95450204a98e47881081/Kerala/Alappuzha/Alappuzha_city/sslc_diploma_plustwo/Experienced/Sunil_Kumar.html
```

Actually there is a CSS file in the specified location( You can see the location in view page source).

I am not able to find out the reason,

Sincerely,

Sunil

Comment: Looks like your http://jobsgang.com/themes/development/templates/resumes/classic_gray/css/style.css is broken and keep redirecting to an default error page or parent page? Can you check if your page is working first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Your css link redirects to another page..
Check it

Comment: Dear Ateş Danış, Thanks for your replay. I am also worried about that. I am not able to find out the reason for that redirect.. Please try to help me. Thanks inadvance

Comment: Please check the css code, i have updated my question with css code, Thanks

Comment: css has nothing to do with redirects, check your .htaccess if you're using apache for any url rewrites and your php code for `header('Location:...')` directives

Comment: Dear Ates, this is the link url of the css file. It is also not loading http://jobsgang.com/themes/development/templates/resumes/classic_gray/css/style.css

Comment: Yes I know, so you can check the .htaccess file as **xception** says or you can try to upload the css file to different location and replace link of it with new location.

Answer (score 0):

Its the problem with your CSS Url . http://jobsgang.com/themes/development/templates/resumes/classic_gray/css/style.css
is redirecting to http://jobsgang.com/themes/development/templates/resumes/classic_gray/css/employerDashBoard.php  with an error message "This webpage has resulted in too many redirects". Chk it out.

Comment: Thanks for your replay . I am not able to find out the reason for that redirect. I have updated my question with the css code. Please take a look in it

Comment: http://jobsgang.com/themes/development/templates/resumes/classic_gray/css/style.css . Actually there is a css file and I am not able to view it from this url